# How to plot an "error circle" using plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a path plot which describes known and estimated data. For the estimated portion, I want to add shaded regions showing the expected error (which is the same in the x and y directions).

I tried simply using an `add_markers` with variable `size`:

```
library(plotly)

data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0),
           y = c(2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3),
           err = c(rep(NA, 6), 0.25, 0.5, 1)) %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_paths(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y
  ) %>%
  add_markers(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    size = ~err,
    marker = list(sizemode = "radius")
  )
```

[image]

This is entirely inadequate, however. The `err` value represents the "radius of the error circle". So the last point (`x=0, y=3`) should have a circle going from `y = 2..4`, but it instead seems to have a radius of around 0.75. I could fix that by tinkering with the `marker.sizeref` argument, but there are other issues. Since the `size` parameter is actually calculated in pixels, it is immune to scale changes: if I zoom in or out, the circles don't change in size. And using the zoom-box to change the aspect ratio should cause the "error circles" to become "error ellipses", which obviously doesn't happen using this method.

Now, I'm aware of plotly `shapes`, but they don't seem to have ellipses and I don't know how to create multiple shapes at once (other than building a list with a for loop or something of the sort).

So, is it possible to create such "error circles" using plotly?

Answer (score 0):

This plots multiple shapes that I have hand entered the values for, and could be a huge pain if you have a lot of these circles to hand enter. It does plot the circles correctly.

```
data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0),
           y = c(2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3),
           err = c(rep(NA, 6), 0.25, 0.5, 1)) %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_paths(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y
  ) %>%
  layout(shapes = list(
           list(type = 'circle',
                       xref= 'x', x0 = -1, x1 = 1,
                       yref= 'y', y0 = 2, y1 = 4,
                       fillcolor = 'rgb(255,0,0)', 
                       line = list(color='rgb(255,0,0)'),
                       opacity = 0.7),
           list(type = 'circle',
                       xref= 'x', x0 = -1.5, x1 = -0.5,
                       yref= 'y', y0 = 1.5, y1 = 0.5,
                       fillcolor = 'rgb(255,0,0)', 
                       line = list(color='rgb(255,0,0)'),
                       opacity = 0.7),
           list(type = 'circle',
                       xref= 'x', x0 = -2.25, x1 = -1.75,
                       yref= 'y', y0 = 0.25, y1 = -0.25,
                       fillcolor = 'rgb(255,0,0)', 
                       line = list(color='rgb(255,0,0)'),
                       opacity = 0.7)
         ))
```

[image]